# How to fill all forms within a page with htmlunit

Tags: htmlunit

Is it possible to fill all forms of a page with random data (and then click on all buttons) using **htmlunit** test? Does anyone know an example?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that:

```
HTMLPage page = /* Your Page */
List<HTMLForm> forms = page.getForms();
for(HTMLForm form : forms) {
  List<HTMLElement> elms = form.getHtmlElementsByTagNames(Arrays.asList("input", "textarea"/*etc*/));
  List<HTMLSubmitInput> submits = new List<HTMLSubmitInput>();
  for(HTMLElement elm : elms) {
    if(elm instanceof HTMLSubmitInput) { 
      submits.add((HTMLSubmitInput) elm);
    } else if (elm instanceof  HtmlTextInput || elm instanceof HtmlPasswordInput) {
      ((HTMLInput) elm).setValue("BLA"/* add your random text here */)
    } // Add more input types if you want
  }
  for(HTMLSubmitInput submit: submits) {
    submit.click(); /*Capture the page here*/
  }
}
```

For more of those input types, you can check out the [HtmlInput JavaDocs](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlInput.html).

Comment: Ok, thank you, but what if I don't know in advance element names?